# Winnovative - PDF generated as image instead of text

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, winnovative

I am using `winnovative` tool to generate PDF.
My problem is PDF which is getting generated is Image not as text.

This issue exists in all browser (Mozila, Chrome and IE)

Is there any fix for this?

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of the software. The current version you can download from http://www.winnovative-software.com/download.aspx should work very well.

Comment: And how to force this behavior in the new versions? I want to unable the user to select the text inside the generated pdf...